# How to test my @NotEmpty with JUnit

Tags: java, junit, annotations

We have to remove almost every framework used in the code. I started
with the @NotEmpty from Hibernate. It was the only class used from
Hibernate, so low hanging fruit we thought.

I wrote the following implementation:

```
import        java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.FIELD;
import        java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;
import        java.lang.annotation.Target;

import        javax.validation.Constraint;
import        javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import        javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import        javax.validation.ReportAsSingleViolation;

@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
@Target({ FIELD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@ReportAsSingleViolation
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1)
public @interface NotEmpty {
    public abstract String message() default "Field has to be filled";
}
```

But it should be tested also of-course. So I wrote the following test:

```
import org.junit.Test;

class NotEmptyClass {
    @NotEmpty
    String notEmpty;

    NotEmptyClass(String value) {
        notEmpty = value;
    }
}

public class NotEmptyTest {
    @Test
    public void firstTest() {
        new NotEmptyClass(null);
    }
}
```

I would expect this test not to pass, but it does. So clearly I am
doing something wrong, but I have no idea what. (This is the first
time I really work with annotations.) I did some Googling but until
now to no avail. So if someone could point me to the right direction …

============

I wrote a better version and published it on GitHub: [My Java annotation example](https://github.com/CecilWesterhof/JavaExamples/tree/master/Annotations)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your test does not fail because 1) you are not actually validating the object your are just initialising it and 2) you are not making any assertions

```
public class NotEmptyTest {
    @Test
    public void firstTest() {
        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

        NotEmptyClass obj = new NotEmptyClass(null);

        // Validate the object
        Set<ConstraintViolation<NotEmptyClass>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(obj);

        // This is the line that will cause your unit test to fail if there are not any violations
        Assert.assertEquals(1, constraintViolations.size());
    }
}
```

I would suggest reading [this tutorial](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html/validator-usingvalidator.html)

Comment: On the statement 'ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();' I get  
    javax.validation.ValidationException: Could not create Configuration.  
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure  
    (Validation.java:175)  
    at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory  
    (Validation.java:50)

Comment: I do something like you suggested, but I would like to do it still a little better. I check that there is exactly one ConstraintViolation, but is there a way to check that it is the right ConstraintViolation?